# Symfony2 default locale prefix

Tags: symfony

i have a problem in the _locale prefix

```
ecommerce:
    resource: "@EcommerceBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
```

it doesn't work when i go to : example.com/post/9

It work only when I added the _locale prefix , I want that it work with the prefix _locale or without the prefix _locale (or set a default prefix _locale)

Thanks

Comment: Use https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is "normal".

```
prefix:   /{_locale}/
```

It mean each url with /xxx will be considered as an EcommerceBundle route.

You should add another prefix before, or delete it.

```
ecommerce:
    resource: "@EcommerceBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /ecommerce/{_locale}/
```

Or as stated above, use [JMSRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle).